# Product page with 2 times css

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, media

Im trying to create a product page, but my boss wants different css for every next photo and text. I need 2 different css styles, that will aply on where the image is. Like the first block will have the image at the left and the second block will have the image on the right.

This is basicly what im trying to do :[image]

I think I could do this with css and some custom classes? So that every added block with text and image will align itself properly without having to edit the css for every block everytime you create a new block. If someone could point me in the right direction on how to achieve this, that would be great !:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are achieving this html by using views then set the rows even and odd patterns and do the CSS according to the even and odd class.